Determining the Probability of f(x) > b for Given Intervals of a and b
Let the function $f(x) = ax + \frac{x}{x-4}$ for $x > 4$. If $a$ is chosen from the numbers 1, 2, 3, 4 and $b$ is chosen from the numbers 4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24, then the probability that $f(x) > b$ holds for all $x$ is ___.
I tried the following code but didn't get the correct answer.
f[x_, a_] := a*x + (x)/(x - 4);
aValues = {1, 2, 3, 4};
bValues = {4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24};
combinations = Tuples[{aValues, bValues}];
validCombinations = 
  Select[combinations, f[x /; x > 4, #[[1]]] > #[[2]] &];
probability = Length[validCombinations]/Length[combinations]


Why do you think you don't get a correct answer? Have you tried taking your code apart piece by piece and deducing which piece of the code is not doing what you expect it to do? Please do this, thoroughly, piece by piece, no rush, then [edit] the question and include your findings. Also help yourself with answers to 323 prior questions you posted on this site, many of which deal with function analysis :)

please please please try and do what @Domen suggested. You often ask questions with no indication of where your attempt has gone wrong. For example, in the problem, what is the minimum value of f[x] for a given value of a?

$Version

(* "14.1.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 16, 2024)" *)

Clear[a, b, f, x, aValues, bValues,
 combinations, validCombinations, probability]

f[x_, a_] := a*x + x/(x - 4);

aValues = {1, 2, 3, 4};
bValues = {4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24};

combinations = Tuples[{aValues, bValues}];

validCombinations = Assuming[x > 4,
  Select[combinations,
   Simplify[f[x, #[[1]]] > #[[2]]] &]]

(* {{1, 4}, {1, 8}, {2, 4}, {2, 8}, {2, 12}, {3, 4}, {3, 8}, {3, 12}, 
   {3, 16}, {4, 4}, {4, 8}, {4, 12}, {4, 16}, {4, 20}, {4, 24}} *)

probability = Length[validCombinations]/Length[combinations]

(* 5/8 *)


Assuming uniform distribution for a and b
First notice that for $x>4$, $f(x)$ diverges to infinity as $x$ goes to infinity, and goes to infinity as $x$ goes to 4 from the right. So the minimum of $f(x)$ is at the critical point of $f(x)$ (there's only one)
red = Reduce[D[f[x, a], x] == 0 && x > 4 && 1 <= a <= 4, x];
xMinLocation = red[[-1, 2]];

minValue[a_] := f[xMinLocation, a] // FullSimplify // Evaluate

minValue[a]

$f_{\text{min}} = \left(\sqrt{\frac{1}{a}}+2\right)^2 a$
The probability that the minimal value of $f(x)$ is greater than $b$ is the same as the probability that $f(x)$ is greater than $b$ on all $x>4$
$$
P(f_{\text{min}}  > b) = P(f(x) > b) \quad \forall \quad x >4
$$
a and b are discrete uniformly distributed (b is in steps of 4 so you just multiply the discrete uniformly distributed r.v. by 4):
aDist = DiscreteUniformDistribution[{1, 4}];
bDist = DiscreteUniformDistribution[{1, 6}];

Probability[
 minValue[a] > 4*b, {a \[Distributed] aDist, b \[Distributed] bDist}]


5/8

And simulation agrees:
nps = 10^4;
N@Total@Table[
    aVal = RandomVariate[aDist];
    bVal = RandomVariate[bDist];
    Boole@Resolve@ForAll[x, x > 4, f[x, aVal] > 4*bVal]
    , nps
    ]/nps


0.6278


Assuming that each combination of the a and b values are equally likely:
a = {1, 2, 3, 4};
b = {4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24};
fmin = Simplify[Minimize[{w  x + x/(x - 4), x > 4}, x][[1]], Assumptions -> w > 0]
(* (1+2 Sqrt[w])^2 *)
probability = Sum[Boole[(fmin /. w -> a[[i]]) > b[[j]]], {i, 1, 4}, {j, 1, 6}]/(4*6)
(* 5/8 *)

